# Database Architecture for Countries/Cities/News

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

I'm developing an application to post news. Could anyone suggest me a best approach keeping performance and Scalability in view

### Approach 1 :

I would like to have Country as a database and cities as a table and post the news to individual table. This way i'm pulling traffic to respective databases/cities

But its very hard to show world news. I need to join multiple databases. I still don't know about the performance here

### Approach 2:

Take a Single database and save the news into multiple cities tables. This way i just need to join multiple table for world news. I don't see a difference between approach 1 and approach 2.

### Approach 3:

Take single Database and post each news w.r.t country_id and city_id. Have proper indexing for country_id and city_id.

I'm inclined towards approach 3, but if there are 1M records and search becomes too heavy isnt ??

Can anyone suggest me an approach please.
I'm using MySQL Database.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no performance different when joining between tables in the same or different databases. Databases are for organization purposes, and make access control easier (because you can make grants for `db.*`), they don't affect how queries are processed.

Comment: What do you suggest is a best possible way to design an architecture like this ?? or any useful links to read though ??

Comment: Sorry, I try to avoid design discussions like this. SO is not really appropriate for them, it's for questions that have objective answers, not opinionated discussion.

Comment: Approach 3 is fairly straight forward. Unless you have a specific performance problem, keeping your data structure simple and normalized will give you the most options in the future. You'll probably want a different engine for search later anyway, e.g. elastic search.

Answer (score 3):

Approach 3 is the only sensible choice. MySQL will handle a million rows without any trouble.

It's pretty simple to build a prototype, stuff 10 million rows of random(ish) data in it, and measure performance. *10 million* is not a typo. When it's practical, test with 10 times the data you expect. Learn to use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html).

You should be able to build this kind of prototype in less than half an hour. It's a good skill to practice.

One database per country and one table per city are poor substitutes for [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html).

Comment: Thanks Mike for the headsup.